# Write the file names of the files to be deleted in a log file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have below section of my script, where i am deleting the files older than 30 days. I am able to do that. But I want to write were, which file is getting deleted.

```
@ echo off

SET dump_path=d:/test/files

SET _CmdResult=NONE

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('forfiles /d -30 /p %dump_path% /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @file" 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR ERROR') DO SET _CmdResult=%%a 


IF "%_CmdResult%" == "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." ( 
   SET errorlevel=0
 ) ELSE ( 
   SET errorlevel=1
 )
 IF "%_CmdResult%" == "NONE" SET errorlevel=0
```

The catch is; I have to handle the exception also, if no files are found older than 30 days. I am able to do that as well.

But I need your help to write the file names of the file which is getting deleted into a log file with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "dump_path=d:\test\files"
set "logFile=d:\test\logFile.txt"

> "%logFile%" 2>nul (
    forfiles /d -30 /p "%dump_path%" /m *.* 
)

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo No files found
) else (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%logFile%") do echo del "%dump_path%\%%~a"
)
```

Just save the log file and check the errorlevel from `forfiles`. If there is no errorlevel, then read from the log file the list of files to delete.

In previous code, delete operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command

*note*: setting the `errorlevel` as you do in your code is not a good idea. If you set a value to the variable, run a command and try to retrieve the `errorlevel`, you will get the value you stored, not the generated one.

If you need to clear the errorlevel, just use `ver>nul`

If you need to set the errorlevel use the `exit n` or `exit /b n` to leave the current process with the indicated `n` errorlevel (`n` numeric), or if you want to continue the current process but set a errorlevel, use `cmd /c exit n`